# Why does my ibpy connection always close automatically

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

my code:

```
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from ib.ext.Order import Order
from ib.opt import Connection, message


def error_handler(msg):

   print "Server Error: %s" % msg

def reply_handler(msg):

   print "Server Response: %s, %s" % (msg.typeName, msg)



if __name__ == "__main__":
 tws_conn = Connection.create(port=7496, clientId=100)
 tws_conn.connect()
 tws_conn.register(error_handler, 'Error')
 tws_conn.registerAll(reply_handler)
```

and the TWS log file:

```
GO 00:27:20:952 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [0:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] Starting new conversation with client on /127.0.0.1
GO 00:27:20:952 JTS-EServerSocketNotifier-232: Starting async queue thread
GO 00:27:20:952 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [0:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] Server version is 76
GO 00:27:20:953 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [0:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] Client version is 62
GO 00:27:20:953 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [0:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] is 3rdParty false
GO 00:27:20:954 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [100:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] Client ID is 100
GO 00:27:20:958 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [100:62:76:1:0:0:0:ERR] Socket connection for client{100} has closed. 
GO 00:27:20:958 JTS-EServerSocket-231: Connection reset
GO 00:27:20:959 JTS-EServerSocket-231: ArEServer: Removing 174597970 with id 100
GO 00:27:20:959 JTS-EServerSocket-231: [100:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] Ending conversation with client{100} at /127.0.0.1
GO 00:27:20:959 JTS-EServerSocketNotifier-232: Terminating async queue thread
GO 00:27:20:959 JTS-EWriter2-233: [100:62:76:1:0:0:0:SYS] Writer thread terminated for socket client{100}.
GO 00:27:21:952 JTS-DeadlockMonitor-26: CPU:cur=0.00% avg=0.67% 30 min avg=0.67% 5 min avg=0.22% 1 min avg=1.02%
GC:called=20 times CPU used=0.09%
Finalizer:cur=0.00% avg=0.01% 30 min avg=0.01% 5 min avg=0.00% 1 min avg=0.00%
Threads Count:curr live=88 curr daemon=52
GO 00:27:47:000 JTS-CCPDispatcherS2-40: Setting time offset to -1282 diff 5579
GO 00:27:47:000 JTS-CCPDispatcherS2-40: Setting time offset to -1282 diff 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your python script ends and with it the socket that `ibpy` has opened to connect to TWS.

The demo samples in the sources of `ibpy` use simple `time.sleep(x)` to make sure some information has been delivered (for example `fancy_marketdata.py`) before the script ends.

Try to remove the `time.sleep(x)` lines and see how the script also ends instantly.

Have a look at other ways to do it like here for example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561626/ibpy-getting-portfolio-information-interactive-broker-python

You may consider running the `ibpy` connection in another thread and control the thread over a `Queue`.